# How to implement message notification in React App?

Tags: django, reactjs, sockets, socket.io, notifications

I am now building an application using React and Redux as the frontend and Django as the backend. What i am trying to realize is whenever an end user upload a file, all the end users that are related to this file should receive a notification.

I am thinking of using websocket/socket.io but I am not sure if that works well with Django. Or any experience or suggestions of using any other technologies to implement the message notification function?

Comment: I think that this question should be on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com instead of here at stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

A simple Google search revealed Django [Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

> Channels is a project that takes Django and extends its abilities beyond HTTP - to handle WebSockets, chat protocols, IoT protocols, and more. It’s built on a Python specification called ASGI.

Comment: So this means i should use Django channel for the backend to handle the front-end websocket right?

Comment: exactly, tinker a little bit with it and it will be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `field_field.files[0].file.slice()` method in javascript you can send a file in chunks over a websocket. Using `field_field.files[0].size` you can get the total size and divide the total of what you've sent and the size of the file to build a progress bar. Make sure you wrap your file writes in the `@sync_to_async` decorator as doing it without that would block the event loop. That method is part of Channels and found in [Asgiref.](https://github.com/django/asgiref)

[Channels Redis](https://github.com/django/channels_redis) can be used to notify any or all of the users that an event has occurred, such as a file being uploaded.